# How do i do grand total of columns in R?

Tags: r, statistics, reporting

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHo85.png)I have a dataset in R, I have to do few columns grand total and based on grand total i have to calculate grand of other columns. For example
df is like

Where I need the sum of cols like price, transaction, qty but my

`x = sum of price/sum of transaction`

and

`y = sum of qty/sum of transaction`

```
ATV = price / transaction
UPT = qty / transactIon
```

How can I do a grand total thing in R?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please don't post images of your code or data.

Answer (score 1):

It is very straightforward to do this in R. I give you the way to do the first part and you could complete the other part.

Here is the code:

```
Price <- c(450, 500, 800)
Grandtotal_Price <- (sum(Price))

> Grandtotal_Price
[1] 1750

Transaction <- c(33, 21, 42, 96)
Grandtotal_transaction <- sum(Transaction)
ATV = Grandtotal_Price / Grandtotal_transaction

> ATV
[1] 9.114583
```